# Get CSV via REST?

Tags: api, export, rest

Is there a way to get CSV-formatted output via a REST call?

We have a 3rd-party app that can import data periodically from a URL pointing to a CSV file, so the aim is to provide it with a Civi URL (probably going to a custom api function) that returns selected data as if it were just a plain CSV file.

EDIT: Civi 4.6.10 currently on WP moving to Drupal

Comment: What CMS and Civi version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Not natively, you would need to write a custom extension to do the relatively simple task of converting array output from the api to csv output.

Comment: After converting to CSV, how would the extension send that format back to the client?  Won't anything from the REST interface be XML or JSON?  Would it make sense to add a "&csv=1" like "&json=1" to CRM_Utils_REST?

Comment: My suggestion was for the extension to define a different path and not use the same rest url as core.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, you can do this using existing plugins and no custom code.

- Build a Drupal View of your CiviCRM data (using [Views module for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) + CiviCRM's [Views CiviCRM](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Views3+Integration) module, part of the CiviCRM download for Drupal).
- Use filters in the View to correctly show the data you want to export to external service.
- Use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to provide a CSV output format of this view.
- Check the View display(s) have appropriate access restrictions (edit settings in View).